# How does python evaluate this?

Tags: python, evaluation

Can someone explain how these results are possible (python 2.6):

```
>>> 1<3>2
True
>>> (1<3)>2
False
>>> 1<(3>2)
False
```

I would think that one of the last two would match the first one, but apparently the operators in the first statement is somehow linked?!

Comment: Why the downvote? I really had no idea what to search for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first example shows [comparison chaining](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in).  `1<3>2` means `1<3 and 3>2` (except each expression is evaluated only once).  This applies to all comparison operators in Python.

Your second two examples force one comparison to be evaluated first, resulting in a boolean value which is then compared with the remaining integer.

Comment: It's worth noting that if the values compared are expressions, they are only evaluated once, so `1 < f() < 2` is not exactly equivalent to `1 < f() and f() < 2`. A closer quivalent would be `x = f(); 1 < x and x < 2`.

Answer (score 4):

In your first case `1<3>2` `1` is actually lesser than `3` and `3` is greater than `2`, so `True`.

In your second case `(1<3)>2` `(1<3)` evaluates as `True` that represented as `1`, so `1` is not greater than `2`.

In your third case `1<(3>2)`, `1` is not lesser than `True` that represented as `1`.

Answer (score 2):

The last two statements compare booleans against an integer:

```
>>> True > 2
False
>>> 1 < True
False
```

The first statement is [comparison chaining](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in), which works for all boolean comparisons in Python. Note from the documentation:

> Comparisons yield boolean values: True or False.

By placing parts of your expression in brackets, those parts get evaluated first and you end up with comparing integers and booleans.

Answer (score 1):

As per [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in),

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise operation. Also unlike C, expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:
>
> comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
>
> comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "<>" | "!="
>                      | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
>
> Comparisons yield boolean values: `True` or `False`.
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Comment: Can you at least put the python documentation text you copied wholesale in a quote?

Comment: That's not what I meant; shihongzhi did it for you.